# MessageBox.Show("First Name,{0}", textBox1.Text);

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like for the input from textbox1.text to be displayed in the place holder {0}
so that if textbox1.text = "Randy" I would like a messagebox to popup and say Firstname,Randy

```
MessageBox.Show("First Name,{0}", textBox1.Text);
```

What happens currently is a messagebox pops up and says First Name,{0}

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's no overload that does formatted output for the `MessageBox` class.  Use `String.Format()` to get your formatted string.

```
MessageBox.Show(String.Format("First Name,{0}", textBox1.Text));
```

To show a message box with a caption, use the `MessageBox.Show(string, string)` overload.  First argument is the message while the second is the caption.

```
MessageBox.Show(String.Format("First Name,{0}", textBox1.Text), // message
                textBox1.Text); // caption (title)
```

Comment: How do I add a title to the messagebox using this way?

Comment: @randy: Refer to the different overloads for `MessageBox.Show()`.  The one you're looking for is [`MessageBox.Show(string, string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20stz12s.aspx)